# Status/news feed?

Tags: facebook, feed

Hello im really new to this and ive searched the web for answers about it.

I wanna create a newsfeed from a facebook "fanpage" and add it to a website to get a newsfeed of statuses showing on the html site. How do i create this?=

Comment: Where have you checked? What programming language are you working on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph API to pull a list of posts from a page wall

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#connections
Example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552%2Ffeed